# Operation on data frame in loop with changing dataframe names

Tags: r, excel, loops, variables

I have six data frames , z1, z2, ...z6. (read from six different sheets of a single excel file).

I need to do subsetting on these data frames and build some models. The process is identical for each of them. I was hoping to do it in a loop but not able to find the right syntax. (I am trying to use paste and assign functions but it does not help). 
For example I want

```
for (i in 1:6){
Z=subset(Zi,Zi$var1==1)
}
```

Zi should be Z1, Z2, Z3 exactly which are already defined. I can generate a variable through paste function which is Z1, Z2 in each iteration like

temp=paste('Z',i,sep='') but I cannot use 'temp' in place of Zi in the above code.

There is some discussion on other threads on similar problem but I am not able to find anything directly related there. If I am missing something, please point me to the right thread.

Comment: Next time [put your data frames in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Need to learn that I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the 'values' in a `list` using `mget`, loop over the `list` (`lapply(..)`) and subset` the rows based on the 'var1' column.

```
lapply(mget(paste0('Z', 1:6)), subset, subset=var1==1)
```

Comment: Not sure if it worked but definitely gave me lot more ideas on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Is are the column names of the data similar? If so, you might want to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

"Z" %>% 
  paste0(1:6) %>% 
  mget %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>%
  filter(var1 == 1)
```